# CSS childs and siblings

Tags: css

I am new in CSS right now. I don't have much experience with CSS children, pseudo classes, siblings. I have like 30 pages of w3school open and can't find the specific thing I need.

I have 2 divs, 1 image in those divs.

But, when I use CSS IMG and change it, it changes both of them, I just want to change one and that's it. I'm using like `IMG.this` and `:` and `>` and both always change size.

I don't understand the coding here; there's so many, like `div.(class) img -code-` and others.

I know is something so simple but can't find the way.

Comment: Do you have any sample code? Create a Codepen.io, jsbin.com, jsfiddle.net snippet so people can readily help you with what you have completed so far.

Comment: Write code code which you have tried

Comment: its just a theory problem emmm....I think is an ID and class problem....

Comment: If you want to apply the css for specific item then use different class and write css for that class only.

Comment: alrady fixed it thx anyways

Answer (score 0):

if you only have 2 images and want to change one of them you can give it a id and style it using that id like shown below.

the image class makes them both a width of 300px and the #image2 id styling then changed the width of the second image

```css
.image img{
  width:300px;
}

#image2 img{
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div> 
<div class="image" id="image2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```